# Can we pass Variables through Stash in Jenkins Checkpoint

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to pass variable assigned in previous stages to next stage of jenkins pipeline. In a continuous build variable is passing properly. but when I use checkpoint in jenkinsfile, i am not to pass the variable which is used in previous stage to next stage

eg:

```
stage('Initial') 
{
  agent {
       node {
         label 'NGC-NIS-VS2017-15-7-6-INTEG'
        }
        Steps
        {
           stash 'env.BUILD_NUMBER', name : "Passing buildnumber" 
         }
}

stage('CheckPoint')
{
    agent none
    steps 
    {
        checkpoint 'HalfWay through'
    }
}

stage("Deploy") {
      agent any
      steps {
        unstash 'Passing buildnumber'
      }
    }
```

when i restarted the build from that checkpoint, i am not able to get the value previous build number.

Comment: How are you checking to verify if the unstash does not work?

Comment: @MattSchuchard It is saying you did not add any files to stash. which means we can't pass any variables through stash ?

Comment: No, you can't do this directly. You'll have to find some way of writing the variables to a file, then saving that file as a stash. [Here are the parameters `stash` takes](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)